# How to convert RDD[List[String]] to RDD[List[Float]]

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

For example, the structure of local file data.txt is:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0
       ...
```

Reading file as RDD[String]:

```
lines = sc.textFile("data.txt")
```

split into RDD[List[String]]:

```
data_temp = lines.map(lambda line: line.split(" "))
```

How to convert into RDD[List[Float]]?

I know `json.loads()` can parse the string, how to do in this case?

Comment: Use Spark CSV reader with `inferSchema` set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert all the strings to floats when splitting the lines:

```
data_temp = line.map(lambda line: [float(i) for i in line.split(" ")])
```

Or you can read the data as a dataframe and infer the types:

```
df = (spark.read
  .schema(schema)
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv("some_input_file.csv"))
```

For more information about different options when reading csv files, see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).